# How to convert video to NTSC (so it can be burned to a DVD) without losing quality?

Tags: ffmpeg, dvd

I have a 1080p mp4 video, and I want to burn a DVD from it. It must be 'mastered' as a DVD, so it can be played back on an older DVD player (i.e. it can't be a data DVD). For the tool that I'm using to make the DVD, I need to convert the video to the correct format with the correct codec before burning. I am in America, so I know that standard is NTSC. I tried converting my video with:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -target ntsc-dvd output.mpg
```

but the result was quite fuzzy and low-res. I did some research and it seems like NTSC only supports up to 720p, but as I understand it, NTSC is still the standard today, and there are HD DVDs. So is there a a way to convert my video to NTSC so that I can burn a DVD without losing resolution?

Please forgive me if this is an ignorant question, and correct me about any false assumptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DVD does not support 720p. It’s only supports 480p/i.

HD DVD was a failed competitor to Blu-ray. Standard DVD players are not forward compatible.